# django related field exists after delete

Tags: python, django

I've an Order model and others models which related with it. An user can delete any of this items and I must perform a check if the order is empty after deletion and set as active False in case true. Some basic code to ilustrate it

```
class Order(models.Model):
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    def empty_order():
         """
         I must implement it
         """

class HomeOrder(models.Model):
    ...
    order = models.OneToOneField(Order, related_name='primary_home')

class TourOrder(models.Model):
    ...
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='tours')
```

I have a post_delete signals that are connected with every of this Models related to Order:

```
post_delete.connect(delete_order_if_empty, sender=HomeOrder)
post_delete.connect(delete_order_if_empty, sender=TourOrder)

def delete_order_if_empty(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.order.empty_order():
        instance.order.active = False
        instance.order.save()
```

An Order can have one Home, so if the Home exists I can do **order.primary_home**, if Home does not exist it will raise an AttributeError because it is an OneToOne relationship.

An Order can have many Tours, so in the **empty_order** method I thought to do some checks as following.

```
def empty_order():
    home = hasattr(self, 'primary_home')  # Avoid AttributeError exception
    tours = self.tours.exists()
    this_order_has_something = primary_home or tours
    return not this_order_has_something
```

Now, when I delete an HomeOrder the signal is raised but the empty_method never realized that this HomeOrder does not exists any more. Example:

```
>>>o=Order.objects.create(...)
>>>o.primary_home # raise AttributeError
>>>h=HomeOrder.objetcs.create(order=o, ...)
>>>o.primary_home  # <HomeOrder: home-xx>
>>>h.delete()
>>>o.primary_home # still <HomeOrder: home-xx> Why?
>>>o.refresh_from_db()   
>>>o.primary_home # again <HomeOrder: home-xx>
```

Comment: Try: `o.primary_home.refresh_from_db()` which should fail. The Python object still exists and is cached on the order. You can also do `print(h)`, but its db entry is no longer there.

Comment: I tried this but it raises me orders.models.DoesNotExist: HomeOrder matching query does not exist